# How should I measure the relationship between a variable containing text and a binomial variable?

Tags: correlation, binomial-distribution, text-mining

I have data in this format:

```
Words,Source,Result
pestology Gomel, cheap, 0
cocreating, cheap, 1
munitioner impersonating nonextinct, cheap, 1
Kolomna, expensive, 1
Enyo's snakemouth, expensive, 0
blueberries backare farriers, cheap, 0
markets rafales, cheap, 0
...
```

http://bit.ly/h2ynoG

How should I determine whether the phrases in column one can explain the Result value?  What if I want to determine which individual words in the phrase are correlated with successful results?

Also, how should I determine whether the data in which Source is cheap is representative of all of the data?

Thanks.

Comment: What assumptions can you make? E.g. can you assume that only one word in each phrase is responsible for the result, and the remaining words are just distractors? Or are there some "word weights" which get summed up to get the final result? Or something else?

Comment: It is unknown if any of the words are meaningful.  How would I determine if the words, either individually or as a phrase, are helpful in predicting the value of Result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start by transforming the phrases into numbers via a document term matrix, with a 1 denoting the presence of a word and 0 being the absence of a word. Then you can perform correlation analysis.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-term_matrix

R Code

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Could you provide an example?  I installed the R tm package, and can create a DocumentTermMatrix from the Words column, but I don't know how to measure the correlation between the terms and the other variables from the data frame.

Comment: See some sample code above

Comment: Looks like you've got me on the right track.  I set the Result to 1 for all lines containing the word, pestology, and I get a non-zero correlation for this word: http://bit.ly/gtWn8c  How do I determine whether the correlations between the words and Result are significantly different for the two values of Source?

Comment: You need to construct confidence intervals on the correlation estimates.                             http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/cor.html

Comment: Do you mean perform separate correlation measurements for the cheap and expensive datasets, and then measure the correlation between these correlations, like this? http://bit.ly/e9DoEk

Comment: Look at conf.int from corr.test for each of the correlations. If the ranges overlap then that suggests that the two values of Source might be combined. But I would also use business knowledge and determine if it makes sense to combine them.

Comment: How do I run cor.test with the document-term matrix containing all of the words in the corpus and the result?  I can do it for a single word, but not for all of the cheap words and cheap results because "'x' and 'y' must have the same length".

Comment: Sounds like it has to do with specific "R" syntax.  I would open it up as a new question.